# Crypto credit/debit card provider - Process of Crypto to Fiat

Tags: exchanges, debitcard, bitcoin-credit-card

How do crypto credit/debit card provider organise their crypto to fiat exchange process?

I thought that they would manually exchange crypto to fiat on exchanges through a bot. However, this would not be instant, right? Even if they used an exchange that allows "market trading" and a bot doing the exchange, I cannot see how that would be instant.

Any ideas how the card providers solved the problem?

EDIT: Could it be that they buy crypto in bulk, thus there does not happen an exchange at the very moment (probably OTC)?

Comment: What card providers are you talking about? I don't think any major ones support cryptocurrencies at all.

Comment: Yes, the major ones do not support it. I am talking about the specialised one: Xapo, Shift, BitPay to name a few. 
The payment processor is either Mastercard or Visa.

Answer (score 1):

there are many card provider services. Wirex is one of the popular bitcoin debit card provider. I found this article with list of [best bitcoin debit card providers](http://coinfunda.com/best-bitcoin-debit-card-top-btc-debit-cards-list/) 
There are exchanges inbuilt within the wallets to convert cryptos into eachonther as well as they support crypto to fiat exchange.

Answer (score 0):

> **I am talking about the specialised one: Xapo, Shift, BitPay**

#### Xapo

Closed

#### BitPay

Pre-paid

#### Shift

It seems you have to have a Coinbase account and authorize Shift to make some use of it. Presumably Shift don't authorise any Visa transaction for which your Coinbase account lacks adequate funds? If Shift have their own Coinbase account they can presumably instantly transfer any amount from any other custodial wallet at Coinbase that they have been authorised to use by the customer.